# Configure device specific global instance variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, idioms, ios-universal-app

I'm currently writing a universal app, and would like to set certain parameters, such as standard button size, globally, depending on device. Currently I am using:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    iVar = 88;
}
else {
    iVar = 44;
}
```

in various places. However, I'd like to run this only once, and set the ivar somewhere globally. I know I could do this in the app delegate, once the app initialises, and declare the variable in the header, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution that is standard practice.

(I am aware that I could use the native image size using xcassets, but I'd like more control than this).

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `Global.h` and declare all global variables in it. Keep only the header file and import the Global.h file in `YourProject-Prefix.pch` like this:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Global.h"
#endif
```

In order to define your global variables, simply open the Global file and put the following line of code, i.e:

```
#define __metricsTableRowHeight 45
#define __metricsTableSectionHeight 45
#define __metricsTableSectionButtonHeight 57
```

Comment: and how are those device specific (i.e. evaluated at run time)?

Comment: As Matthias says, the iVar in question needs to be initialised to 1 of 2 different values, depending on the device... So somewhere I need to execute the code in my question.